# Studies on the effect of combinations of dietary phenols, caloric fasting, and fiber on those with IBS

Tags: nutrition, irritable-bowel-syndrome, gut-microbiota-flora

I'm interested in how gut bacteria ecosystems are affected when no protein and no digestible carbohydrates are consumed *in combination with* dietary phenols, and indigestible carbohydrates like fiber. I'm particularly interested in the effects on IBS-D sufferers.

Does caloric fasting in combination with polyphenols and supplemental fiber improve the symptoms of IBS-D sufferers over those who fast using only water, and control groups?

I'm hypothesizing that indigestible fiber and polyphenols are preferentially consumed by symbiotic microbes over pathogenic microbes and even more so while fasting and that would make IBS-D symptoms significantly improved over control, but perhaps pathogenic bacteria are equally nourished or harmed by some dietary interventions.

I know that fasting per se is often found to be beneficial. Here is one [example](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1207%2Fs15327558ijbm1303_4). I know that polyphenols and fiber may be beneficial. Here is one [example](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40199-019-00284-1#main-content). When I search PLOS ONE for "fasting IBS" and other terms, I often get hits related to the fasting breath test, results for 'fast' as in 'quick', and other unrelated results.

I also know that caloric restriction has different effect than taking in no calories for more than a day but eating ad libitum most days, so research like [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6643/11/7/1565) is not helpful. I'm not sure how to find research that includes complete caloric fasting or even a fasting-mimicking diet in combination with fiber/polyphenols.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your question is. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @CareyGregory Fasting, dietary polyphenols, dietary fiber, etc have effects individually. Is there research on the combined effects for IBS-D sufferers?

Comment: Your response needs to be an edit to the question, not a comment. I would recommend adding a single sentence that distills your question. You've got 5 paragraphs of text but no actual question.

Comment: @CareyGregory, which word or words are not clear? Are you saying I should rephrase, 'Studies on the effect of combinations of dietary phenols, caloric fasting, and fiber on those with IBS" to "[What are s]tudies on the effect of combinations of dietary phenols, caloric fasting, and fiber on those with IBS[-D?]" or change "Does caloric fasting in combination with polyphenols and supplemental fiber improve the symptoms of IBS-D sufferers over those who fast using only water, and control groups?" somehow, or something else?

Comment: You're overthinking this. Take a look at your "question." It contains only a single question mark. Is that sentence your question? I doubt it. So just spell out a simple sentence with your question. I guess it would be the question you asked in the second comment here, but it's your question so I can't be sure.